# Hyper VM network disconnects after Server restarts from a crash

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, centos7

We have setup CentOS 7 in VM at Windows 10 Host using Hyper-V 10, its connected via External vSwitch,

We have power issues that cause the Host Windows machine power down unexpectedly, after reboot the VM starts but we are unable to connect to CentOS 7 unless we stop and restart the VM at Hyper-V,

on other hand if we shutdown the Host Windows Machine and restart we are able to connect to CentOS 7 without resetting the VM

Comment: I'm not Hyper-V expert (we use KVM), however from the description I guess, that the sudden power down caused that VMs weren't suspended properly and lost it's memory snapshot. Then after power on, VMs were just resumed, like if it was properly suspended, but that wasn't stable state.

Comment: On proper host shutdown, VMs should be either suspended correctly or OS shutdown should be initiated (in KVM it's possible to select from these options).

Comment: I have experienced something similar before. The cause of the problem was the mac address of the NIC. In hyper-v it was set to "auto generate"  and when hyper-v restarts it generate new mac address for the nic. This will make centos (in my experience 6.x) think its a new card. So it will not load the configuration for the nic and it wil not bring it up. To solve this I had to set a static mac on the nic.

Comment: Hi @MrZach that works for me, please add this as a answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced something similar before. The cause of the problem was the mac address of the NIC. In hyper-v it was set to "auto generate" and when hyper-v restarts it generate new mac address for the nic. This will make centos (in my experience 6.x) think its a new card. So it will not load the configuration for the nic and it wil not bring it up. To solve this I had to set a static mac on the nic.